# SqlCommand SUM decimal issue with output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, converters, sqlcommand

I have got this code which `SUM number(9,2)` values in `SQL DB`, but the output is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`.

I know I have to Convert it somehow but have no idea how?

Would you please suggest me something? Thank you very much for your time.

```
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(price) AS sumprice FROM client WHERE subkey="+key,conn);
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    textBox20.Text = sc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking up when to use `ExecuteNonQuery` and when not too.. this is something that you can easily google for future reference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what you are looking is `ExecuteScalar()` not `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

```
int _result = Convert.ToInt32(sc.ExecuteScalar());
```

- [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

For proper coding

- parameterize the value to avoid `sql injection`
- use `using` statement for proper object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle exceptions